# ArrayList of Array which contains TreeNode

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, tree, binary-tree

I want to create an Arraylist of array which consist of treeNodes. My trial was

```
ArrayList<Arrays<treeNode>> aList = new ArrayList<Arrays<treeNode>>();
Arrays<TreeNode> aNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
```

But it gives an error. (utils are included)

What is the right way of writing this? My aim is to find the minimum depth of a node in a Binary tree(just to find the minimum not to find that node itself, I ll put levels into arraylist, once size is not 2^j, then min level is j-1).

Thanks in advance, for any help/hint/solutions...

Comment: it says remove type argument. and it points the  <Arrays>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class is a util class, not the type you'd use for an array. The Arrays class never takes a generic argument, which is what your error is telling you.

If you want an ArrayList that contains arrays, then you're probably looking for something like this:

```
ArrayList<TreeNode[]> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I thought the same and psyched myself out, thought for a second there was some weird collection I missed.

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise not mixing arrays and `ArrayList`s. Better to nest a `List` inside a `List`.

```
List<List<TreeNode>> aList  = new ArrayList<>();
List<TreeNode>       aNodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note that the empty `<>` diamonds are shorthand for:

```
List<List<TreeNode>> aList  = new ArrayList<List<TreeNode>>();
List<TreeNode>       aNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<TreeNode[]> myList = new ArrayList<TreeNode[]>();

TreeNode[] aNodes = new TreeNode[fixedSizeArray];
```

This is how you can create list of arrays and arrays.. based on your description, I would suggest, refer to some java examples that does smiler things like OSPF etc.. and see what kind of datastructures are used and how.